# Simplify system functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

Consider the code defining two constants:

```
a=Cos[t]
b=Sin[t]
```

Suppose that we have another value in terms of `Cos[t]` and `Sin[t]`, for example,

```
c=2*Cos[t]+Sin[t]^2
```

How to show the result of `c` in terms of `a` and `b`, that is, instead of the line above I'd like my computations being showed as

```
c=2*a+b^2
```

In other words, how to ask Mathematica to recognize `Cos[t]` as `a`?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do something similar is to use rules instead of using equals.

```
rules = {Cos[t] -> a, Sin[t] -> b}
2 Cos[t]^2 + 3 Sin[t] //. rules

2 a^2 + 3 b
```

Comment: +1 Please read my answer as a comment to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is as follow:

```
Unprotect[Cos, Sin];
Cos[t_] = a;
Sin[t_] = b;
c = 2*Cos[t] + Sin[t]^2

(*2 a + b^2*)
```

But be careful if you are going to use Cos or Sin to do calculations. they will return a and b.

Comment: I'll use only for symbolic computations to simplify some rotations.

Answer (score 0):

My way is: (no guarantee to be the best way)

```
a = Cos[_];
rules = a -> Hold[a]
Cos[t] + 2 Cos[u] + 3 /. rules
```

It returns `3 + 3 Hold[a]`. If you don't put `a` with `Hold`, *Mathematica* will evalute it, which we do not expect.
You can also write a function to generate a list of rules when you need several such replaces.
The benefit of writing `rules = a -> Hold[a]` (rather than `rules = Cos[_] -> t`, which `t` is another symbol to distinguish) is that you need not to **care** or to **trace** what is the definition of symbol `a`. Every time you use the rule, it simply means **replacing the definition of a by a**, namely `a -> Hold[a]`.

(**update**)
In order to increase the readability, using `HoldForm` is also a good choice.

```
a = Cos[_];
rules = a -> HoldForm[a]
sentence = Cos[t] + 2 Cos[u] + 3 /. rules
```

It returns `3 + 3 a`.

```
sentence // FullForm
```

It returns `Plus[3,Times[3,HoldForm[a]]]`.

So if you want to textually change "a" to a number or an another symbol:

```
In[]:= sentence
In[]:= sentence /. HoldForm[a] -> x
In[]:= sentence /. HoldForm[a] -> 15

Out[]= 3 + 3 a
Out[]= 3 + 3 x
Out[]= 48
```